# Wordpress Image Paths

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently developing a new site on Wordpress to replace an old Drupal site. The site is currently being developed on 'dev.website.com', and will be moved to 'website.com' once completed.

I'd like to use a relative image path like 'images/logo.png' instead of the absolute path as it'll make the switch a lot easier, as I won't have to manually remove 'dev.' before every single reference to a file path on the site.

Is there a plugin to do this, or a setting within the Wordpress admin itself? I've looked at loads of articles but they seem to be pretty complex for what I thought could be a simple fix.

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: If you're using `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` in your theme file it shouldn't be a problem? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directoy'); ?>/images/image.jpg` I create a lot of child themes and this works perfectly.

You can also define a constant with `define(IMGPATH, STYLESHEETPATH . '/images');` and use something `<?php IMGPATH . '/logo.png';`

`STYLESHEETPATH` is a constant that WordPress uses.

Comment: How do I actually use this? Do I need to add '<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directoy'); ?>' before every single image file, or is there somewhere in particular that I should put it?

Comment: Yes. if you are pointing to a logo you will use something like this `<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />`.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm amazed that there's not a simpler way to set up an '/images' folder for speed when adding images - it's got to be incredibly monotonous to have to type out that extra code for every single image.

Comment: simpler way? `$path = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');` and use `$path` each time.

Comment: Good idea. You can also define a constant with `define(IMGPATH, STYLESHEETPATH . '/images');` and use something `<?php IMGPATH . '/logo.png';`

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution for importing images

`<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/image.jpg">`